# After some aggregation stages, I want to filter the array within the document that matches with the conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have 2 collections

1. external_S_P_FLAT_main_api

2. external_S_C_FLAT_main_api

The collection has data as below.

```
"external_S_P_FLAT_main_api": [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef588674d"
    },
    "data.pricing.material": "TG11",
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000001",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef588674e"
    },
    "data.pricing.material": "TG12",
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000002",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef588674f"
    },
    "data.pricing.material": "TG14",
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000003",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef5886750"
    },
    "data.pricing.material": "TG2341",
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000004",
  }
]
"external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef5886751"
    },
    "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000001",
    "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-09-12",
    "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000001 - 3rd",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef5886752"
    },
    "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000002",
    "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2022-03-02",
    "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000002 - 1st",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef5886753"
    },
    "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000003",
    "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25",
    "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000003 - 1st",
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "654c6a594d0867aef5886754"
    },
    "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000004",
    "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25",
    "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000004 - 2nd",
  }
]
```

Below is the query I am executing:

```
db.external_S_P_FLAT_main_api.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data.pricing.controlling_area": "$data.pricing.controlling_area"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data.pricing.cost_center": "$data.pricing.cost_center"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "external_S_C_FLAT_main_api",
      let: {
        let_data__pricing__controlling_area: "$external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data.pricing.controlling_area",
        let_data__pricing__cost_center: "$external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data.pricing.cost_center"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$data.costcenter.controlling_area",
                    "$$let_data__pricing__controlling_area"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$data.costcenter.cost_center",
                    "$$let_data__pricing__cost_center"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data.pricing.controlling_area": 0,
      "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data.pricing.cost_center": 0,
      // from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api: 0,
    }
  }
])
```

Below is the output comes:

`` ` ``

```
[
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000001",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG11",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886751"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000001",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000001 - 3rd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-09-12"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886752"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000002",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000002 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2022-03-02"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886753"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000003",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000003 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886754"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000004",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000004 - 2nd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000002",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG12",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886751"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000001",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000001 - 3rd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-09-12"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886752"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000002",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000002 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2022-03-02"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886753"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000003",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000003 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886754"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000004",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000004 - 2nd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000003",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG14",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886751"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000001",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000001 - 3rd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-09-12"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886752"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000002",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000002 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2022-03-02"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886753"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000003",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000003 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886754"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000004",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000004 - 2nd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000004",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG2341",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886751"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000001",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000001 - 3rd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-09-12"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886752"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000002",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000002 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2022-03-02"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886753"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000003",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000003 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886754"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000004",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000004 - 2nd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want the output in such a way that it has single element in the array from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api which is matching with the condition as

value of data.pricing.cost_center matches with from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api.data.costcenter.cost_center and

value of data.pricing.controlling_area matches with from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api.data.costcenter.controlling_area

So the expected output should be as below:

`` ` ``

```
[
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000001",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG11",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886751"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000001",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000001 - 3rd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-09-12"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000002",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG12",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886752"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000002",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000002 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2022-03-02"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000003",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG14",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886753"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000003",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000003 - 1st",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "data.pricing.controlling_area": "AJ00",
    "data.pricing.cost_center": "DE000004",
    "data.pricing.material": "TG2341",
    "external_S_P_FLAT_main_api_data": {
      "pricing": {}
    },
    "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("654c6a594d0867aef5886754"),
        "data.costcenter.controlling_area": "AJ00",
        "data.costcenter.cost_center": "DE000004",
        "data.costcenter.long_description": "CC DE000004 - 2nd",
        "data.costcenter.valid_from_date": "2023-10-25"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What am I missing? How shall I get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your field contains dot(s), getting the field value with `$` is inappropriate as it treats that you are accessing the field in the (nested) object. For example: `data.pricing.controlling_area`, you are able to get the field value with `$` only when its structure is as below:

```
"data": {
  "pricing": {
    "controlling_area": "AJ00"
  }
}
```

To get the field that the field contains dot(s), you need the [`$getField`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/).

The same goes for if you want to add/set a field with dot(s), you need the [`$setField`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/).

I would recommend removing the first two stages as unnecessary to add a field where you can get the value from the original field and also you need to remove those fields in the projection stage.

```
db.external_S_P_FLAT_main_api.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "external_S_C_FLAT_main_api",
      let: {
        let_data__pricing__controlling_area: {
          $getField: "data.pricing.controlling_area"
        },
        let_data__pricing__cost_center: {
          $getField: "data.pricing.cost_center"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    {
                      $getField: "data.costcenter.controlling_area"
                    },
                    "$$let_data__pricing__controlling_area"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    {
                      $getField: "data.costcenter.cost_center"
                    },
                    "$$let_data__pricing__cost_center"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "from_external_S_C_FLAT_main_api"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SztHGrD_U1q)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The above change is working on the Mongo version v5.0 onwards

I have Mongo with version v4.4.3.

Is it possible to get the results with the version v4.4.3?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that works with the earliest version like 4.4. Either you need to upgrade your MongoDB version or *migrate* your documents not to have the field with dot.

Comment: You may read: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30575